# How do I match text between two rule matches

Tags: regex

I need to return all text after my match rule all the way up to the next new line character.

I have this so far which just gets everything after the match but I just want the word Smith

```
(?<=name=sn\nuserdetails.attribute.value=).*
```

Here is part of the string:

==\nuserdetails.attribute.name=sn\nuserdetails.attribute.value=Smith\nuserdetails.attribute.name=cn\nuserdetails.attribute.value

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: Running this in .Net and trying to get data out of text returned from a REST response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=name=sn\\nuserdetails\.attribute\.value=)[^\\n]+
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/aM5oU3/8

or

```
(?<=name=sn\\nuserdetails\.attribute\.value=)(?:(?!\\n).)+
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/aM5oU3/7

Comment: Why are you using this `(?:(?!\\n).)+` ? it's same as `[^\n]+`

Comment: @AvinashRaj have given both the options.

Comment: no, go for negative lookahead only if it's not possible through negated char class.

Comment: This works fine in a regex parser but cannot get this to work in .NET. It simply doesnt match anything

Answer (score 1):

You need use this `\n` pattern to match a newline character not `\\n`.

```
(?<=name=sn\nuserdetails\.attribute\.value=).*
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the *characters* `\n`

```
(?<=name=sn\\nuserdetails.attribute.value=)(.*?)\\n
```

http://regex101.com/r/zB0eL1/1

Answer (score 0):

How about

`(?<=name=sn\\nuserdetails.attribute.value=)[^\\]*\\n`

Or

`(?<=name=sn\\nuserdetails.attribute.value=)[^\\]*`

see the example http://regex101.com/r/dT9rH3/1